# Heat exchanger analysis

Tags: heat

Hi i have an task of calculating the rates of heat transfer for hot and cold water and discuss the discrepancy's. There are three tests with each one increasing flow rate of the water the same for hot and cold. The water is being fed into a shell and tube heat exchanger. The transfer rates for the hot is 661w and cold is 658w for test 1, test 2 hot is 972w and cold 963w and test 3 hot is 1318w for hot and cold is 1379w (which id guess is wrong duo to heat transferring from hot to cold). What are the discrepancys? Is the rate of transfer the amount of energy transferred from the hot water to the cold?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out Heat Transfer by Simonson. Cross flow, Counter flow? Parallel flow?

Comment: It's counter flow.

Comment: For test 3, the hot temp difference is 8.5 and for cold temp difference it is 8.8 so this is causing the transfer rate to be more for the cold. Why does this have a big factor for heat transfer?

Comment: In order to get a thorough answer with useful and practical information, it's worth spending some more effort in posing the question in a well-formatted manner and as precise as it can be. Currently, the way it is formatted and with the information given, it looks like an exam question, and your efforts are not observable.